# GFCI trips when reset and many devices are connected to it

Tags: gfci

I have connected a GFCI 15A to a 20A breaker although all outlets have the typical 15A NEMA. Whenever I turn it on it trips if any devices are connected. If I disconnect everything it doesn't trip. Any ideas on why this may be happening?

Without the GFCI (when I remove it and put a regular outlet) everything operates normally.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Hot & Neutral on both Line (back to the breaker) & Load (connecting to the other outlets) are connected the right away? Also, any outlet with hot/neutral reversed (should never happen, but it does...) could cause a problem. Are you sure "any" devices? Do you have a simple device - e.g., a nightlight - that you can test with another GFCI to make sure it is OK and then test with this GFCI, one outlet at a time?

Comment: The line and load lines are correct. This GFCI won't work if they are not correct (I know because I initially put them the wrong way). I thought it was the surge protector, so I removed and put another one. It worked for a while then tripped again. When the surge protector was on the off, no tripping. Then I would turn it on and it would trip. I tried several devices and all seemed to trip the GFCI. Does it matter if a 15A is on a 20A breaker if I am not drawing more than 15A. Also does it matter than all devices try to suck power at once? (although even one device did the same.

Comment: Shoot us a photo of how the receptacle is wired.  Either it *is* a line/load issue, or one of your devices has a ground fault.  You would troubleshoot the latter by plugging in only one device at a time.  It does not matter if all devices draw at once, that is normal.

Comment: Even though you are sure you have line/load correct, there still could be a problem with one of the chained load outlets. Try disconnecting load and plugging devices ONLY into the GFCI outlet directly and see if it trips.